# Create a MSSQL Trigger that updates a table column

Tags: sql-server

peter here... Im creating an auction system and i need to create a trigger that will update a column called isSold from 0 to 1 automatically but only when the auction end date time is equal to the current date time and also only if the item has bids on it. is this possible using triggers?

my tables are as follows...... (bold for primary key, italic for foreign key)

auction (**auctionID**, *bidID*, *itemID*)

bids (**bidID**, *consumerID*, bidDateTime, bidAmount)

items (**itemID**, *categoryID*, *infoID*, *distributerID*, + other item information)

info (**infoID**, startPrice, buyNowPrice, listingDateTime, endDateTime, isSold, soldPrice)

So you can see from the tables above i need to join all four table to achieve what i need. So again what i need to do is update the 'isSold' column from the table info from its default value which is 0 to 1 automatically when the endDateTime column from the table info is equal to the current date time but only if the item is located in the auction table.

i hope I've made sense, i hope someone can help me understand triggers a little more.

thanks in advance, peter brennan

Comment: You can't use Triggers for this, they only fire on specific table actions (insert, update, delete) You should look into SQL jobs..

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to consider whether `isSold` needs to be stored at all - it might be easier to just apply the appropriate logic during `SELECT`.

Comment: After a few hours of googling I thought this was the case. Thanks for confirming that. Cheers guys.